# Android stop location

Tags: android, gps, location

i'm using it to recover the location of the user :

```
        locManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);         

    locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,5000,1000, this);
    Location location = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

The problem is, the location seems to be always enabled when me i just want to use it ONE time.

How can i stop the location (when the users "pause" the application etc) ?

I tried it, in my function "onPause" :

```
    locManager.removeUpdates(this);
    locManager = null;
```

But it's not running.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call

```
super.onPause()
```

So the onPause() function would look like:

```
public void onPause(){
    locManager.removeUpdates(locListener);
    super.onPause();
}
```

If you have not set a locationListener and getting a NullPointerException, wrap the removeUpdates in a null check:

```
if (locManager != null)
    locManager.removeUpdates(this);
```

Comment: in my case i haven't set a "locListener", i wrote "this" in the function requestLocationUpdates, and when i want to remove, i tried it : locManager.removeUpdates(this); and i have an error nullpointerexception. why ?

Comment: i found my error, it was because i launched two location manager (one in splashscreen, one on the other activity), and i forgot it, i wanted to close the bad location manager... now it's running, thx !

Comment: Good deal. Hope I helped.